# CORS (Cross origin resource sharing) not supported by Fusion Tables?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, cors, google-fusion-tables

Judging by the comments on [issue 554](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=554), I would think that Fusion Tables had support for [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) requests. Trying the following though gives a cross site error (in Chrome):

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201906375")
xhr.send()
```

The error is: *Origin http://[domain] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

The following example works fine (for comparison), a simple PHP page where I set the "CORS" header and echo the origin server back like, "hello example.com":

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET","http://skipperkongen.dk/services/corstest/hellocors.php")
xhr.send()
```

I must admit that I've found nowhere on the web that explicitly says that fusion tables supports CORS, but I kind of expect it (judging also by the comments in the issue)...

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Here's a curl request that shows that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not returned on the response. However I know nothing of the status of CORS support in Fusion Tables: curl -H "Origin: foobar.com" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1" "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201906375" --verbose

Comment: Hmm yes, that was my conclusion as well. I find it a bit odd, it would be so easy to stick that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the responses, and it would improve the product a great deal IMO.

Comment: Btw, guess you looked at my homepage :-) choice of User-agent. Well, glad someone read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers were updated only for the (undocumented and subject to change) JSONP interface:

http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=&jsonCallback=

Comment: To me, that seems like a wierd choice? Since CORS and JSONP both accomplish the same thing, namely cross site javascript web service calls. CORS would have value exactly on the non-JSONP interface, IMO. Thanks for your answer :-)